# How to update model of dynamically created Component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created component Dynamically 
using this code:

```
   const inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map(
        (inputName) => {
            return { provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName] };
        });

    const resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);
    // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);

    // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

    // We create the component using the factory and the injector
    const component = factory.create(injector);

    // We insert the component into the dom container
    this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);

    // Destroy the previously created component
    if (this.currentComponent) {
        this.currentComponent.destroy();
    }

    this.currentComponent = component;
}
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
```

Component name is ChatComponent having one array in it 
messages

But now whenever  some notification will come from server I will to update 
I want to push message in messages array.

like this...`

```
    export class NotificationHandler {
   constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => ChatComponent)) private _chatComponent: ChatComponent) { }

   receiveMessage(chatMessage) {
      console.log('sending message', this._chatComponent.messages);
   this._chatComponent.messages.push(chatMessage);
  }
}
```

But seems like this is different instance of that component as messages array is undefined in this, while on UI I can see messages are visible

Comment: You probably need to provide your UI code. I suspect your UI is just checking for messages reference and not for any push changes.

Comment: Only child components of ChatComponent can inject a reference to ChatComponent and get the correct instance. NotificationHandler looks like a service. You might inject the service into ChatComponent and ChatComponent will pull the messages using rxjs for example